# how to get the size of an indirect array in bash?

Tags: bash, array, size, reference

Without using eval.

this wont work:

```
astr=(a b c)    
str="#astr[@]"
echo "${!str}"
```

Comment: AFAIK, what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: Why would you _not_ use `eval`? Note that variable indirection is just as bad as `eval` in `bash` if you can't guarantee the content of `$str` is safe (as in `str='a[$(reboot)]'`)

Answer (score 3):

From a tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839567/1422630), I managed to do this:

```
astr=(a b c)
declare -n astrRef="astr"
echo ${#astrRef[@]}
```

This allows also to create such array or simply assign values thru indirection:

```
declare -n astrRef="astr"
astrRef=(d e f)
declare -p astrRef astr
astrRef+=(g)
declare -p astrRef astr
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this, which works at least on **bash 3.x** and above:

```bsh
astr=(a b c)
str=astr[@]              # Our reference to an array
local arr=("${!str}")    # Copy into an array using indirect ref
echo ${#arr[*]}
# 3

bstr=("a foo" "a bar" "a fox" "a buzz")
str=bstr[@]
local arr=("${!str}")
echo ${#arr[*]}
# 4
```

We use `local` keyword to keep our working variable `arr` local to the function, but this is optional. In fact because of the limitation of bash, `arr` can be used also to access the elements in the (indirect) array, like:

```
echo ${arr[1]}       # Print 2nd element
echo ${#arr[1]}      # ... print its size
```

(Tested on **bash 3.1.23**, bash 4.3.48 and 4.4.12)